# Jenkins Publish TestNG Results not working

Tags: jenkins, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I am running *Jenkins 1.571*.  I am building my project with a `pom.xml`.  I have two executions of `maven-surefire-plugin` to execute two testng suites in a forked mode.

But Jenkins build#/testReport page shows test results for only first suite.  Build logs show test cases from both suites are successfully executed.

I want to include results from both suites into report, so I added `Publish TestNG Results` plug-in, but that doesn't show any results at all.  Any idea on what I might be missing?

In my Jenkins configuration, I specified `'TestNG XML report pattern' = '**/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml'`

Build log shows:

```
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml
Did not find any matching files.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

My relevant pom.xml:

```
<!-- run unit test cases -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <environmentVariables>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
        </environmentVariables>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${basedir}/src/test/testngSuite1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>special-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${basedir}/src/test/testngSuite2.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I found out that I need to use forward slash for TestNG plugin to locate the file (My Jenkins runs on Windows).

```
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: C:/workspace/project/target/surefire-reports/Suite1/UnitTests.xml;C:/workspace/project/target/surefire-reports/Suite2/UnitTests.xml
Saving reports...
Processing 'C:\programs\Jenkins\jobs\project\builds\2014-10-02_21-57-48\testng\testng-results-1.xml'
Processing 'C:\programs\Jenkins\jobs\project\builds\2014-10-02_21-57-48\testng\testng-results.xml'
TestNG Reports Processing: FINISH
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Also this reference helped:
http://www.seleniumtests.com/p/testing-forum.html#nabble-td5001883

Comment: Do you really resolve this issue by using forward slash? My jenkins runs on centos, and now I got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

1.Select "Editable Email Notification" on Post-Build actions.

2.In the Default Content section : remove $DEFAULT_CONTENT.Place the following code to inject your html report into the default content :-

${FILE,path=”relative path to html file”}

Eg: ${FILE,path=”MyWorkspace/MyProj/test-output/emailable-report.html”}

More detailed steps given below in my tech blog:-

https://itisatechiesworld.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/including-testng-reports-within-the-jenkins-email-notifications/

Also let me know if you have any other reporting related questions using Jenkins. 
Will try to help out. :)

Regards,
VJ

Comment: If this is your blog, you need to declare your affiliation to it, otherwise it's considered spam